# Check if a string is a ordered sublist of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, boolean

Let's say that I have a list with the following pattern:

```
lst=['A','B','C','D']
```

and I have the three following strings

```
str1='BCD'
str2='ABD'
str3='CD'
```

As you can see, `str1` and `str3` are both ordered substrings of the pattern in lst, while `str2` isn't. I need to find a way to  check whether this is true or not.

Can this be done? Should lst be something like `['ABCD']` instead of `['A','B','C','D']` for it to work?

Comment: How you present the list or string isn't all that important because you can convert back and forth easily. I would probably use backtracking in my first try, but you should write the code, and then present it with a failing test case. Right now you just have a "write my code" post. [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply join the list to a string with

```
lstAsString = ''.join(lst)
```

and then check for a string if it's a part of this with the `in` operator

```
if str2 in lstAsString:
   print("This is an ordered substring")
```

Comment: For completeness: This is based on your examples. I would have counted every one of them as an 'ordered substring' because the letters `ABD` are part of `ABCD` in order, just with a hole in them. If you were to go for this interpretation of 'ordered substrings', an elementwise comparison would probably be the way to go (traverse haystack until first letter in needle is found, then look for the second letter next until the full needle is found or the haystack has been fully traversed)